# ubuntu 12.04lts mobile broadband loose connecton after every few minutes

Tags: 12.04

Ubuntu 12.04lts mobile broadband loose connection after every few minutes.
I am using Samsung mobile it is gt-s3653.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these tips

- keep all the setup on stable ground.
- restart mobile, even computer if possible.
- Check if your configuration looks like this.

  ```
  MTU: automatic
  Method(ipv4): AUTOMATIC(DHCP)
  method(ipv6): AUTOMATIC
  Available to all users is selected
  ```

These settings are available under the **Edit connections** menu from the top bar.
[image]

> You can see that my phone is samsung GT B5330, so the settings should work hopefully!